# Detect phone's display settings through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom

I have a web application that runs in a webviewer and needs to be responsive on both PC and mobile. I've gotten it to look good on mobile, but now I want to change the way things look based on the mobile device's display settings.

On my android phone, navigating to settings / display / text size, there are five options: small, normal, large, extra large and huge. I want to be able to detect which of these settings is selected through javascript and then modify my HTML accordingly.

I have tried the following HTML DOM properties to see if they change based on the device's display settings, but unfortunately they don't:

1) screen.width

2) screen.pixelDepth

3) window.visualViewport.scale

4) window.devicePixelRatio

Please suggest, if there is any way I could detect these display settings?

Comment: Did you search before posting your question? The first item in your list is already very easy to find anywhere.

Comment: @J.Meijer Yes, I've spent a couple of hours searching for this before posting. I think you may have misunderstood the list, those are the items that DO NOT change based on display settings of an android device. I'm trying to find some property (other than those listed) that changes based on the device's display settings.

Comment: A lot of the things you mention are included in the `window.screen` variable, try it out in your console.

Comment: @J.Meijer I did.... let me try to clarify this again:
screen.width is 360 on my phone when display setting = large;
screen.width is 360 on my phone when display setting = small;

I am trying to find something that changes when display setting of phone changes. So far, all of the things I have listed do not change based on the phone's display settings. Do you know of any property that does change?

Comment: If you are trying to change CSS based on screen size you might have to take a look at media queries, if not I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @J.Meijer I'm using media queries already and they're working perfectly for detecting different screen sizes. But they're not detecting different display settings on the same phone as far as I know. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript to read a phone's text size settings.